# How do I display a single image in PyTorch?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

How do I display a PyTorch `Tensor` of shape `(3, 224, 224)` representing a 224x224 RGB image?
Using `plt.imshow(image)` gives the error:

> TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Given a `Tensor` representing the image, use [`.permute()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html#torch.permute) to put the channels as the last dimension:

```
plt.imshow(  tensor_image.permute(1, 2, 0)  )
```

Note: [`permute` does not copy or allocate memory](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/swap-axes-in-pytorch/970/7), and  [`from_numpy()` doesn't either.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48482787/5353461)

Comment: Wow thank you... This worked for me... I was trying to do tensor_image.numpy().reshape([224,224,3])  and visualize it using cv2.imshow() But i was not getting the actual image... whats going wrong here??

Comment: @DevashishPrasad The problem is that `reshape([224,224,3])` doesn't do the same thing that `permute(1, 2, 0)` does. The `permute` function is similar to transposing a matrix, where rows become columns and columns become rows. The `reshape` function does something totally unrelated that I don't know how to describe concisely. In short, `reshape` is the wrong function.

Comment: what is the shape of `tensor_image `?

Comment: An arguably more readable alternative is `plt.imshow(torch.einsum('cwh->whc', tensor_image))`

Answer (score 21):

As you can see `matplotlib` works fine even without conversion to `numpy` array. But PyTorch Tensors ("Image tensors") are channel first, so to use them with `matplotlib` you need to reshape it:

Code:

```
from scipy.misc import face
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

np_image = face()
print(type(np_image), np_image.shape)
tensor_image = torch.from_numpy(np_image)
print(type(tensor_image), tensor_image.shape)
# reshape to channel first:
tensor_image = tensor_image.view(tensor_image.shape[2], tensor_image.shape[0], tensor_image.shape[1])
print(type(tensor_image), tensor_image.shape)

# If you try to plot image with shape (C, H, W)
# You will get TypeError:
# plt.imshow(tensor_image)

# So we need to reshape it to (H, W, C):
tensor_image = tensor_image.view(tensor_image.shape[1], tensor_image.shape[2], tensor_image.shape[0])
print(type(tensor_image), tensor_image.shape)

plt.imshow(tensor_image)
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (768, 1024, 3)
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([768, 1024, 3])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([3, 768, 1024])
<class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([768, 1024, 3])
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me, see updated question with the tensor's shape.

Answer (score 10):

PyTorch modules processing image data expect tensors in the format **C × H × W**.<sup>1</sup>
Whereas PILLow and Matplotlib expect image arrays in the format **H × W × C**.<sup>2</sup>

You can easily convert tensors to/[from](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.pil_to_tensor(pic)) this format with a TorchVision transform:

```py
from torchvision.transforms import functional as F

F.to_pil_image(image_tensor)
```

Or by directly permuting the axes:

```py
image_tensor.permute(1,2,0)
```

---

1. > PyTorch modules dealing with image data require tensors to be laid out as **C × H × W** : channels, height, and width, respectively.
2. > Note how we have to use `permute` to change the order of the axes from **C × H × W** to **H × W × C** to match what Matplotlib expects.
   >
   > - [*Deep Learning with PyTorch*](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

Given the image is loaded as described and stored in the variable `image`:

```
plt.imshow(transforms.ToPILImage()(image), interpolation="bicubic")
#transforms.ToPILImage()(image).show() # Alternatively
```

---

Or as [Soumith suggested](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-show-a-image-in-jupyter-notebook-with-pytorch-easily/1229/4?u=ataraxy):

> ```
> def show(img):
>     npimg = img.numpy()
>     plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)), interpolation='nearest')
> ```

Comment: import torchvision.transforms # maybe add the import to the code

Answer (score 4):

A complete example given an image pathname `img_path`:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open(img_path)
plt.imshow(transforms.ToPILImage()(transforms.ToTensor()(image)), interpolation="bicubic")
```

Note that `transforms.*` return a [class](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage), which is why the funky bracketing.

Answer (score 3):

Torch is in shape of channel,height,width need to convert it into height,width, channel so permute.

```
plt.imshow(white_torch.permute(1, 2, 0))
```

Or directly if you want

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.io import read_image
import torchvision.transforms as T

!wget 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553284965-83fd3e82fa5a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8NHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80'  -O white_horse.jpg

white_torch = torchvision.io.read_image('white_horse.jpg')

T.ToPILImage()(white_torch)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use show_image from fastai

```
from fastai.vision.all import show_image
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple function to visualize the pytorch tensor using matplotlib.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

def show(*imgs):
    '''
     input imgs can be single or multiple tensor(s), this function uses matplotlib to visualize.
     Single input example:
     show(x) gives the visualization of x, where x should be a torch.Tensor
        if x is a 4D tensor (like image batch with the size of b(atch)*c(hannel)*h(eight)*w(eight), this function splits x in batch dimension, showing b subplots in total, where each subplot displays first 3 channels (3*h*w) at most. 
        if x is a 3D tensor, this function shows first 3 channels at most (in RGB format)
        if x is a 2D tensor, it will be shown as grayscale map
     
     Multiple input example:      
     show(x,y,z) produces three windows, displaying x, y, z respectively, where x,y,z can be in any form described above.
    '''
    img_idx = 0
    for img in imgs:
        img_idx +=1
        plt.figure(img_idx)
        if isinstance(img, torch.Tensor):
            img = img.detach().cpu()

            if img.dim()==4: # 4D tensor
                bz = img.shape[0]
                c = img.shape[1]
                if bz==1 and c==1:  # single grayscale image
                    img=img.squeeze()
                elif bz==1 and c==3: # single RGB image
                    img=img.squeeze()
                    img=img.permute(1,2,0)
                elif bz==1 and c > 3: # multiple feature maps
                    img = img[:,0:3,:,:]
                    img = img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)[:]
                    print('warning: more than 3 channels! only channels 0,1,2 are preserved!')
                elif bz > 1 and c == 1:  # multiple grayscale images
                    img=img.squeeze()
                elif bz > 1 and c == 3:  # multiple RGB images
                    img = img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
                elif bz > 1 and c > 3:  # multiple feature maps
                    img = img[:,0:3,:,:]
                    img = img.permute(0, 2, 3, 1)[:]
                    print('warning: more than 3 channels! only channels 0,1,2 are preserved!')
                else:
                    raise Exception("unsupported type!  " + str(img.size()))
            elif img.dim()==3: # 3D tensor
                bz = 1
                c = img.shape[0]
                if c == 1:  # grayscale
                    img=img.squeeze()
                elif c == 3:  # RGB
                    img = img.permute(1, 2, 0)
                else:
                    raise Exception("unsupported type!  " + str(img.size()))
            elif img.dim()==2:
                pass
            else:
                raise Exception("unsupported type!  "+str(img.size()))


            img = img.numpy()  # convert to numpy
            img = img.squeeze()
            if bz ==1:
                plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
                # plt.colorbar()
                # plt.show()
            else:
                for idx in range(0,bz):
                    plt.subplot(int(bz**0.5),int(np.ceil(bz/int(bz**0.5))),int(idx+1))
                    plt.imshow(img[idx], cmap='gray')

        else:
            raise Exception("unsupported type:  "+str(type(img)))
```