# Why isn't RandomCrop inserting the padding in pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am getting that `RandomCrop` isn't putting the padding when I create my images. Why is it?

---

Reproducible script 1

todo with cifar...

---

Reproducible script 2:
code:

```
def check_size_of_mini_imagenet_original_img():
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import torch
    import os
    seed = 0
    os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = str(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    np.random.seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)

    import learn2learn
    batch_size = 5
    kwargs: dict = dict(name='mini-imagenet', train_ways=2, train_samples=2, test_ways=2, test_samples=2)
    kwargs['data_augmentation'] = 'lee2019'
    benchmark: learn2learn.BenchmarkTasksets = learn2learn.vision.benchmarks.get_tasksets(**kwargs)
    tasksets = [(split, getattr(benchmark, split)) for split in splits]
    for i, (split, taskset) in enumerate(tasksets):
        print(f'{taskset=}')
        print(f'{taskset.dataset.dataset.transform=}')
        for task_num in range(batch_size):
            X, y = taskset.sample()
            print(f'{X.size()=}')
            assert X.size(2) == 84
            print(f'{y.size()=}')
            print(f'{y=}')
            for img_idx in range(X.size(0)):
                visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(X[img_idx], show_img_now=True)
                if img_idx >= 5:  # print 5 images only
                    break
            # visualize_pytorch_batch_of_imgs(X, show_img_now=True)
            print()
            if task_num >= 4:  # so to get a MI image finally (note omniglot does not have padding at train...oops!)
                break
            break
        break
```

and

```
def visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(tensor_image: torch.Tensor, show_img_now: bool = False):
    """
    Due to channel orders not agreeing in pt and matplot lib.
    Given a Tensor representing the image, use .permute() to put the channels as the last dimension:

    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53623472/how-do-i-display-a-single-image-in-pytorch
    """
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    assert len(tensor_image.size()) == 3, f'Err your tensor is the wrong shape {tensor_image.size()=}' \
                                          f'likely it should have been a single tensor with 3 channels' \
                                          f'i.e. CHW.'
    if tensor_image.size(0) == 3:  # three chanels
        plt.imshow(tensor_image.permute(1, 2, 0))
    else:
        plt.imshow(tensor_image)
    if show_img_now:
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

images here: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/376#issuecomment-1319368831

first one:

[image]

---

I am getting odd images despite printing the transform the data is using:

```
-- splits[i]='train'
taskset=<learn2learn.data.task_dataset.TaskDataset object at 0x7fbc38345880>
taskset.dataset.dataset.datasets[0].dataset.transform=Compose(
    ToPILImage()
    RandomCrop(size=(84, 84), padding=8)
    ColorJitter(brightness=[0.6, 1.4], contrast=[0.6, 1.4], saturation=[0.6, 1.4], hue=None)
    RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)
    ToTensor()
    Normalize(mean=[0.47214064400000005, 0.45330829125490196, 0.4099612805098039], std=[0.2771838538039216, 0.26775040952941176, 0.28449041290196075])
)
```

but the padding is missing:
[image]

but when I use this instead:

```
    train_data_transform = Compose([
        RandomResizedCrop((size - padding*2, size - padding*2), scale=scale, ratio=ratio),
        Pad(padding=padding),
        ColorJitter(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4),
        RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        ToTensor(),
        Normalize(mean=mean, std=std),
    ])
```

it seems to work:
[image]
why don't **both** have the 8 and 8 padding on both sides I expect?

---

I tried seeing the images with mini-imagenet for [torch-meta](https://github.com/tristandeleu/pytorch-maml/blob/master/train.py) and it also didn't seem the padding was there:

```
task_num=0
Compose(
    RandomCrop(size=(84, 84), padding=8)
    RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5)
    ColorJitter(brightness=[0.6, 1.4], contrast=[0.6, 1.4], saturation=[0.6, 1.4], hue=[-0.2, 0.2])
    ToTensor()
    Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
)
X.size()=torch.Size([25, 3, 84, 84])
```

The code is much harder to make compact and reproducible but you can see my `torchmeta_plot_images_is_the_padding_there` ultimate-utils library.

For now since 2 data sets say that padding is not being inserted despite the transform saying it should be I am concluding there is a bug in pytorch or my pytorch version or I just don't understand RandomCrop. But [the description](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop.html) is clear to me:

```
padding (int or sequence, optional) –

Optional padding on each border of the image. Default is None. If a single int is provided this is used to pad all borders.
```

and the [normal padding](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Pad.html#torchvision.transforms.Pad) `Pad(...)` says something very similar:

```
padding (int or sequence) –

Padding on each border. If a single int is provided this is used to pad all borders.
```

so what else could go wrong? The bottom img I provided with a pad is done with the above `Pad()` function not with RandomCrop.

---

cross:

- gitissues: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/376
- pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-isnt-randomcrop-inserting-the-padding-in-pytorch/166244

Comment: I think this is a bug in pytorch: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/89253

Answer (score 0):

They are padded to 84+8 then cropped back to 84: you can see the black padding on each image (eg, on the left for the 2nd image).

I discovered & confirmed that by doing it on cifar. But note this NOT what [the docs say for RandomCrop](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomCrop.html):

> Optional padding on each border of the image. Default is None. If a single int is provided this is used to pad all borders.

it says something very similar [to pad](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Pad.html#torchvision.transforms.Pad):

> Padding on each border. If a single int is provided this is used to pad all borders.

See: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/376#issuecomment-1319405466

I am going to report this to pytorch as a bug https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/89253. Reproducible code in cifar:

```
def check_padding_random_crop_cifar_pure_torch():
    # -
    import sys
    print(f'python version: {sys.version=}')
    import torch
    print(f'{torch.__version__=}')
    # -
    from uutils.plot.image_visualization import visualize_pytorch_tensor_img
    from torchvision.transforms import RandomCrop

    # - for determinism
    import random
    random.seed(0)
    import torch
    torch.manual_seed(0)
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(0)

    # -
    from pathlib import Path
    root = Path('~/data/').expanduser()
    import torch
    import torchvision
    # - test tensor imgs
    from torchvision.transforms import Resize
    from torchvision.transforms import Pad
    from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
    from torchvision.transforms import Compose

    # -- see if pad doubles length
    print(f'--- test padding doubles length with Pad(...)')
    transform = Compose([Resize((32, 32)), Pad(padding=4), ToTensor()])
    train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                          transform=transform,
                                          target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long))
    transform = Compose([Resize((32, 32)), Pad(padding=8), ToTensor()])
    test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                         transform=transform,
                                         target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long))
    # - test padding doubles length
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    loader = DataLoader(train)
    x, y = next(iter(loader))
    print(f'{x[0].size()=}')
    assert x[0].size(2) == 32 + 4 * 2
    assert x[0].size(2) == 32 + 8
    visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(x[0], show_img_now=True)
    #
    loader = DataLoader(test)
    x, y = next(iter(loader))
    print(f'{x[0].size()=}')
    assert x.size(2) == 32 + 8 * 2
    assert x.size(2) == 32 + 16
    visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(x[0], show_img_now=True)

    # -- see if RandomCrop also puts the pad
    print(f'--- test RandomCrop indeed puts padding')
    transform = Compose([Resize((32, 32)), RandomCrop(28, padding=8), ToTensor()])
    train = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                          transform=transform,
                                          target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long))
    transform = Compose([Resize((32, 32)), RandomCrop(28), ToTensor()])
    test = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR100(root=root, train=True, download=True,
                                         transform=transform,
                                         target_transform=lambda data: torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.long))
    # - test that the padding is there visually
    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
    loader = DataLoader(train)
    x, y = next(iter(loader))
    print(f'{x[0].size()=}')
    assert x[0].size(2) == 28
    visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(x[0], show_img_now=True)
    #
    loader = DataLoader(test)
    x, y = next(iter(loader))
    print(f'{x[0].size()=}')
    assert x.size(2) == 28
    visualize_pytorch_tensor_img(x[0], show_img_now=True
```