# How to pre-load numpy data into a buffer like io.BytesIO to make it seekable?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, bytesio

Following function basically returns **numpy.ndarray**

```
def getimage(id):
     img = self.coco.loadImgs(id)
     I = io.imread(img['coco_url'])
     return I #returns 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The **getimage** function being called from main:

```
x = load.getimage(id).
x = torch.load(x)
```

**Error thrown:**

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'seek'. You can only torch.load from a file that is seekable. Please pre-load the data into a buffer like io.BytesIO and try to load from it instead.
```

Comment: seems `touch.load` only load a function. If what you want to do is just to transfer a numpy array to torch. just use `torch.from_numpy(x)`

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.load) say, `torch.load`

> Loads an object saved with torch.save() from a **file**.

To convert `numpy.ndarray` to `torch.Tensor` you want to use [`torch.from_numpy`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.from_numpy), documented clearly as

> Creates a Tensor from a numpy.ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

Use `torch.as_tensor` instead of `torch.load`, and you won't have to create a buffer.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482787/pytorch-memory-model-torch-from-numpy-vs-torch-tensor) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54260202/781938).

If you want the pytorch tensor to be a copy of your numpy array, use `torch.tensor(arr)`. If you want the torch.Tensor to share the same memory buffer, then use `torch.as_tensor(arr)`. PyTorch will then reuse the buffer if it can.

If you really wanna make a buffer from your numpy array, use the BytesIO class from io and initialize it with `arr.tobytes()` like `stream = io.BytesIO(arr.tobytes())`. YMMV though; I just tried `torch.load` with a stream object from this and torch complained:

```
import io

import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 4, 5])
stream = io.BytesIO(a.tobytes())  # implements seek()
torch.load(stream)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
...
UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x03'.
```

If you want to get that to work, you probably have to adjust the bytestream that numpy is generating. Good luck.